# Multithreading - window first closed, then created, even though in code the method for creation is called first

Tags: c#, multithreading, window

This is my code that gets executed:

```
OpenMyWindowInNewThread(1280, 1024, 5);
//do some stuff
CloseMyWindow();
```

And here are the methods:

```
public void OpenMyWindowInNewThread(int width, int height, int top)
    {
        thread = new Thread(x => OpenMyWindow(width, height, top));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void CloseMyWindow()
    {
        if (myWindow != null)
        {
            myWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                myWindow.Close();
                myWindow = null;
            }));
        }
    }

private void OpenMyWindow(int width, int height, int top)
    {
        myWindow = new MyView();
        myWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(MyWindow_Closed);

        myWindow.Width = width;
        myWindow.Height = height;
        myWindow.Top = top;
        myWindow.Left = 0;

        myWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When I call the first code for the first time, the screen is shown and closes, as it should. However, when I execute the code for the second time, here's what happens: OpenMyWindowInNewThread() gets called first, then OpenMyWindow(), then the if condition in the CloseMyWindow() method, and AFTER THAT, the call of the MyView() constructor in the OpenMyWindow() method. So, the window never gets closed because first it's closed, and than it's created.

Why is this happening? Can someone explain?

Comment: You are using a separate thread to create the new window.  That thread is set to background priority.  There is no guarantee that it will execute before close call.  This is a typical race condition.  Use a manualresetevent and block in the close window until that gets triggered

Comment: Don't create multiple UI threads.  Just don't.  Use a single UI thread for your entire application.  You're only putting yourself in a world of hurt trying to deal with multiple message loops.

Comment: Your description actually doesn't make sense. It's not possible for `myWindow` to be set to the new form reference until _after_ the constructor returns. So `CloseMyWindow()` couldn't be seeing it non-null before the constructor. That said, as others have noted yes you do have a race here, and yes you should be doing all of your UI on one thread. If you want to show a dialog while some other processing is going on, show the dialog in the UI thread, and use `BackgroundWorker` or some other secondary thread to do the other processing (which likely shouldn't be done on the main UI thread anyway!)

Comment: @Servy Well what do you suggest using as alternative instead of multiple threads?

Comment: @petko_stankoski Just do everything with a single UI thread.  Don't make the form modal, if you don't want it to be modal.  Whatever you're trying to do with 2 UI threads, you can almost certainly do with just 1 much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two threads accessing the window; the thread that closes the window is running the close method before the thread performing the open completes its operation. The simplest way to solve this is to lock the opening and closing of the window. As already mentioned, multiple UI threads are not an easy concept and it can get very, very messy!

```
private static object _syncLock = new object();

public void CloseMyWindow()
{
    lock(_syncLock)
    {
        if (myWindow != null)
        {
            myWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                myWindow.Close();
                myWindow = null;
            }));
        }
    }
}

private void OpenMyWindow(int width, int height, int top)
{
    lock(_syncLock)
    {
        myWindow = new MyView();
        myWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(MyWindow_Closed);

        myWindow.Width = width;
        myWindow.Height = height;
        myWindow.Top = top;
        myWindow.Left = 0;

        myWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```